# Does varnish ignore first_byte_timeout for pipe requests?

Tags: varnish

There is a note at https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/reference/vcl.html that says

> bereq.first_byte_timeout
>      The time in seconds to wait for the
>   first byte from the backend. Not available in pipe mode.

Does this mean that the first_byte_timeout is ignored for all piped requests to the backend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is correct.

As the documentation states about `pipe`:

> pipe is only used when Varnish for some reason can’t handle the pass.
>   pipe reads the request, pushes in onty the backend *only* pushes bytes
>   back and forth, with no other actions taken.

You won't even see the `X-Varnish`-headers appear in piped requests.